# Can I manually create rail bridges?

Tags: simcity-2013

In one of the maps (not sure which one off hand), there is an avenue with a rail bridge going over it when you first load the map. The bridge is within your city limits rather than outside of it. It would be nice if I could replicate this functionality in other places where I need a rail to cross my roads.

**Is there a way I can manually create a rail bridge?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of. While there's no bridges in the SimCity toolbox if are fortunate enough to be on a map with a small gradient you are in luck!

http://ca.ign.com/wikis/simcity/Manual_Overpass_Technique

[image]

1. draw a dirt road well back from where want the intersection (parallel to the road that will go over.
2. Use the $$$ straight path -- place it perpendicular to the road from step1
3. Edit the park from step 2 and extended a few times. First addition will extend the first park and the make a T with 2-3 more parks.
4. Build 2 roads that go from the ground level and go up to the elevated park.
5. Delete parks.
6. Connected both road segments
7. Profit?

It's pretty disappointing that bridges aren't in-game (seems like it would be simple enough in the interface as a ploppable). And since rails don't carry power/sewage/etc it wouldn't mess with services either!

Comment: Very interesting. So no "legal" way to do it, but by god that is intriguing. Still helpful if I have a map that can make it work. Thanks!